# Add icons to google map v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google map v2 in my android project.
I know that its possible to add custom markers.

But I'm asking if it is possible to add custom icons in the map? for example: plane icons or ship icons and drag it to any location?? 
like what in the screenShot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any drawable as your marker. Like this

```
MarkerOptions marker= new MarkerOptions()
        .position(location)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
                         fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_cab_pickup));

map.addMarker( marker );
```

Comment: Ok great idea, but is it possible to locate this marker by drag and drop it in my target location on map?

Comment: Sure, but you asked about one exact and I answered your question. If you got other questions, then you should place new ones on SO. Do not mix many questions - that is not helping anyone following archives in future

Comment: ok thanks so much, please if you got the answer for my question to tell me.

Comment: ok, this is my second question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512597/drag-and-drop-icons-to-google-map-v2-android