# drag and drop icons to google map v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google map v2 in my android project.
I know that its possible to add custom markers as an icons as shown in the following code:

```
MarkerOptions marker= new MarkerOptions()
    .position(location)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
                     fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_cab_pickup));

 map.addMarker( marker );
```

Is there are any possibility to move this icons by drag and drop to any location on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `MarkerOptions.draggable(true)`. Also check `GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener` , if you want to know when user drags your Marker.